# Redirect incoming WAN connection to other WAN host with iptables

Tags: iptables

I have router with Linux. I want to redirect incoming WAN connections with specified port to some other WAN host:port.

I've tryed do this standard way:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 81 -j DNAT --to-destination <Other WAN host>:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But it seems doesn't work. Is this rules works for WAN-to-WAN or WAN-to-LAN only? My router is ASUS RT-N16 with asuswrt-merlin firmware if this matters.